# Call of anonymous function (vanilla js, pure js, no jquery)

Tags: javascript

I want to grab browser version and OS from useragent via js - this is a practicing example (cause yes - I know - feature detection is how you do it properly ;).

I stumbled across a little library that does so and now I'm trying to understand whats going on.

See this Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPWZGE?editors=001

obviously by running `bowser.version` - you get the version extracted from the browsers useragent. However the function *bowser* itself is an anonymous function - even though I can access elements within this function which has to do with this part of the code

```
!function (name, definition) {
  var module;
  var define;
  if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = definition();
  else if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) define(definition);
  else this[name] = definition();
}
```

To be honest I have hardly any idea whats going on there - can someone please explain what those lines are doing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Basically it searches for the surrounding environment: commons or amd or plain browser.

Comment: But in what way does it help me to refer to things inside the anonymous function? Cause if I remove this `!function` part - the code breaks...

Comment: actually there is probably some code missing here. I assume the code goes on like this: `( 'someName', function(){ /* more code */ }`, which provides the parameters to that IIFE.

Comment: yes - please see the linked Codepen!

Comment: So what's the problem? The IIFE gets two parameters: modulename and definition. It then looks in what environment it is executed and attaches the module then in the correct way.

Comment: The problem is, that I would like to understand how the process you described works in detail. Could you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so step by step ...

first you have an IIFE

```
!function( name, definition ) {
  // some code
}( 'bowser', function(){
  // your module code
});
```

this calls the first function immediately with two parameters: the name of the module (here "bowser") and the actual definition function. In that definition function you create the module: You define any objects, properties and whatever else it needs to work. Important point is: You interface (the view the "outside" has on your module, has to be returned by that defintion function (in your codepen this is line 282: `return bowser;`).

The outer function then determines, *how* to publish your module:

First it looks for a CommonJS environment:

```
typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports
```

This would be used, e.g., inside NodeJS. If it found the respective objects, it will export your module as a CommonJS module: `module.exports = definition()`.

If this was not a CommonJS environment, the script looks, if it is an AMD (for example, requireJS):

```
typeof define == 'function' && define.amd
```

Again, if that matches, the module is exported as a AMD module: `define(definition)`.

Finally, if this is neither CommonJS nor AMD, the script assumes it is a (vanilla) browser or something similar and just attaches the module to the global namespace:

```
this[name] = definition();
```

Note, that each time the definition function is called and the return value is exported as a module. This is why your definition function has to return the module interface.